# (iphone) submit app for world-wide or specific countries

Tags: iphone, submit, publish

I'd like to eventually submit my app for world-wide access.
However, I'd like to submit to specific countries first.

I wonder if I can gradually broaden the countries where my app will be sold.
And, if there's a way to do it, would it be any different from submitting it world-wide from the beginning.

Would I still manage just one binary for all the countries that I gradually add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your app country by country availability in the Rights and Pricing section on ITunesConnect. You will not have to handle more than one binary, it's always the same binary, you just change on which countries it will be available on the same way you can change the price.

Comment: Thanks, had same problem.